# Implementing a TDMA protocol using Python

Tags: python, networking

Just wondering how one would go about implementing the TDMA protocol using Python. I have searched the documentation (and online) but found nothing I thought was relevant.

I have a few sensors which I would like to use to gather data and send over a wireless network.

Is this possible using Python, or how would one be advised (in general) to approach the problem.

Comment: TDMA is implemented in hardware.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So for a novice such as myself, wishing to achieve the above stated aims; do I (a) Buy a router that implements this protocol, (b) adjust settings on standard (compatible) router to enable TDMA, (c) otherwise?  I have been googling about TDMA but all I can find is research papers and tutorials explaining what TDMA is, I get the concept (as much as my knowledge base enables me to), I just don't know how to get data from point A to point B using the protocol.

Comment: TDMA is a layer-1 protocol, so it is inherent in a link. For example, a T1 line uses TDMA to break the link up into 24 different time slots. If you have a T1 line, then you use TDMA, but it is transparent to any application you have. You application doesn't know if you have a T1, ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, etc. as the layer-1 protocol. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In terms of what I am trying to accomplish; I have provided an extremely high level explanation in my original post/question. In the hope of providing further clarity on the issue; The basic premise is; I have some sensors, I have an android device. I want to transmit data (wireless) from sensors to android device for processing via Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). From our discussion I am beginning to see that it is a physical layer protocol which I have no control over from the app layer. I suppose I am wondering how do we determine/influence the underlying protocols being used? Sorry noob here

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you want to do round-robin software polling.